# how to use python to deal with two file at the same time

Tags: python

I want to using python to open two files at the same time, read one line from each of them then do some operations. Then read the next line from each of then and do some operation,then the next next line...I want to know how can I do this. It seems that `for` loop cannot do this job.

Comment: How do you know that a for loop doesn't work? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried many times

Comment: Post your attempt in the question and we can try to help you fix it.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Also, look up [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file1 = open("some_file")
file2 = open("other_file")

for some_line,other_line in zip(file1,file2):
    #do something silly

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

note that `itertools.izip` may be prefered if you dont want to store the whole file in memory ...

also note that this will finish when the end of either file is reached...

Answer (score 0):

Why not read each file into a list each element in the list holds 1 line.

Once you have both files loaded to your lists you can work line by line (index by index) through your list doing whatever comparisons/operations you require.

Answer (score 0):

you can put inside a loop like that:

```
for x in range(0, n):
    read onde line
    read the other line
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
fin1 = open('file1')
fin2 = open('file2')

content1 = fin1.readlines()
content2 = fin2.readlines()

length = len(content1)

for i in range(length):
    line1, line2 = content1[i].rstrip('\n'),content2[i].rstrip('\n')
    # do something

fin1.close()
fin2.close()
```